# Receving error: Procedure or function has too many arguments specified

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, for-loop, stored-procedures

The exception is thrown with the last possibility (subtract_QtyFromStock_Ex < 0). "Procedure or function DeleteFromtb_QtyEx has too many arguments specified." even the stated procedure isn't to be called inside the loop in this possibility.

I checked the number of parameters
I don't use a global sqlcommand
I tested the function separately and it's doing well

The stored procedure with the problem

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[DeleteFromtb_QtyEx]
@autoCodeIdentifier int
As
Delete from tb_Quantity_Expire
where tb_Quantity_Expire.item_auto_code=@autoCodeIdentifier
```

The code at DataAccessLayer

```
public void ExecuteCommand(string stored_procedure, SqlParameter[] param)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(stored_procedure, con);

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        if(param != null)
        {

            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
        }
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Code at the class

```
public void DeleteFromtb_QtyEx(int autoCodeIdentifier)
    {
        Cls_DataAccessLayer DAL = new Cls_DataAccessLayer();
        DAL.OpenCon();
        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[1];
        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@autoCodeIdentifier", SqlDbType.Int);
        param[0].Value = autoCodeIdentifier;

        DAL.ExecuteCommand("DeleteFromtb_QtyEx", param);
        DAL.CloseCon();
    }
```

Code on btn_click

```
private void btnTender_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            decimal qty_entered = 
            Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
            decimal stk = 
            Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
            decimal subtract = stk - qty_entered;
            if (subtract < 0)
            {
Cls.DeleteFromtb_QtyEx(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value));
                Cls.InsertTotb_QtyEx(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value), subtract);
            }else if(subtract==0)
            {
                Cls.DeleteFromtb_QtyEx(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value));
                Cls.InsertTotb_QtyEx(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value), subtract);




            }else if (subtract > 0)
            {
                DataTable dt_QtyEx = new DataTable();
                dt_QtyEx = Cls.SelectFromtb_QtyEx(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value));
                decimal subtract_QtyFromStock_Ex = 0;
                //decimal qty = Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);

                for (int x = 0; x < dt_QtyEx.Rows.Count; x++)
                {
                    if (x == 0)
                    {
                        subtract_QtyFromStock_Ex = Convert.ToDecimal(dt_QtyEx.Rows[x][2]) - qty_entered;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        subtract_QtyFromStock_Ex = Convert.ToDecimal(dt_QtyEx.Rows[x][2]) - (0 - subtract_QtyFromStock_Ex);

                    }
                    if (subtract_QtyFromStock_Ex > 0)
                    {
                        Cls.Updatetb_QtyEx(Convert.ToInt32(dt_QtyEx.Rows[x][0]), Convert.ToDateTime(dt_QtyEx.Rows[x][1]), subtract_QtyFromStock_Ex);

                        break;
                    }
                    else if (subtract_QtyFromStock_Ex == 0)
                    {
                        Cls.DeleteFromtb_QtyEx_Expire(Convert.ToInt32(dt_QtyEx.Rows[x][0]), Convert.ToDateTime(dt_QtyEx.Rows[x][1]));

                        break;
                    }
                    else if (subtract_QtyFromStock_Ex < 0)
                    {
                        Cls.DeleteFromtb_QtyEx_Expire(Convert.ToInt32(dt_QtyEx.Rows[x][0]), Convert.ToDateTime(dt_QtyEx.Rows[x][1]));

                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Using SQL Profiler to see exactly what the command being passed to the server is is might help diagnose what's going on

Comment: If you had to edit your question title to include the phrase "not duplicate" because that title already exists, then perhaps your question **is** a duplicate?

Comment: The function you posted is : public void DeleteFromtb_QtyEx(int autoCodeIdentifier).  The one you are calling is DeleteFromtb_QtyEx_Expire.  The are not the same.

Comment: Also, what's the code of the method `DeleteFromtb_QtyEx_Expire`, which is the method being called in the condition `subtract_QtyFromStock_Ex < 0`? You only show the code for `DeleteFromtb_QtyEx`

Comment: Are you sure that the SP on the database you're targeting is what you think it is? For example, is it possible that there's multiple versions of `DeleteFromtb_QtyEx` in different schemas? A *very* common error is to simply confuse what SP you're hitting. If the *actual* resolved SP doesn't have a parameter (because it is a half-way complete version): boom. As a side note: you aren't disposing the command correctly. I *highly* recommend using tools like "dapper" which *hugely* simplify working with ADO.NET

Comment: As @Marc suggested, try calling the sproc including the schema name, e.g. DAL.ExecuteCommand("dbo.DeleteFromtb_QtyEx", param);

Comment: DAL.ExecuteCommand("DeleteFromtb_QtyEx", param); @preciousbetine

Comment: @DavidG, I reviewd all similar questions one by one

Comment: @jdweng, Here is the problem. I don't call function ( DeleteFromtb_QtyEx(int autoCodeIdentifier)) inside the inner loop even though the thrown exception is related to it

Comment: Thank You All.....The exception is thrown because of the horrible mistake I did by calling the stored procedure <DeleteFromtb_QtyEx> in the function for <DeleteFromtb_QtyEx_Expire>

Answer (score 0):

Thank You All.....The exception is thrown because of the horrible mistake I did by calling the stored procedure "DeleteFromtb_QtyEx" 
in the function for the other stored procedure "DeleteFromtb_QtyEx_Expire"